# OOM error when collecting dataframe for local transformations

Tags: python, apache-spark, databricks

```
x = sqlContext.sql("select * from db.table LIMIT 1000000")
x = x.withColumn("col_78", blank_as_null("col_78"))
x = x.na.fill({'col_2': 0, 'col_3': 0, 'col_82': 0, 'col_99': 0, 'col_21': 0, 'col_22': 0, 'col_43': 0, 'col_19': " "})
ps = x.toPandas()
ps['col_8'] = ps['col_8'].astype(float)
ps['col_9'] = ps['col_9'].astype(float)
ps['col_10'] = ps['col_10'].astype(float)
ps['col_11'] = ps['col_11'].astype(float)
ps['col_12'] = ps['col_12'].astype(float)
ps['col_13'] = ps['col_13'].astype(float)
ps.to_excel("TESTBIG.xlsx", index=False)
```

This code is throwing an OOM exception.  At an unknown line (since I am using databricks).  My driver of my cluster has 128GB and this is the only task running on it.  I have also set these settings on my driver -

```
spark.driver.maxResultSize 40g
spark.driver.memory 60g
```

The data coming in is around 2GB.  So even with massive memory leakage, I should not be running into any issues.   ~100K limit works fine.

What else could the issue be?

Comment: Isn't it because you are converting into pandas? Aren't you supposed to do that in chunks?